# Swift 3: Segmented Control into TableView. Selected index is lost when I reload table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a custom UITableView and a custom UITableViewCell with a UISegmentedControl. That cell is inside the first row of the table.

The problem is I'm using valueChanged event to load data from json and when I reload the tableview, the select index goes back to the first segment automatically. How can I fix this?

This is part of my code:

```
@IBAction func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            loadIdeas(idRole:[0,1], id_user: 1, estado: "todas")

        case 1:
            loadIdeas(idRole:[0,1], id_user: 1, estado: "aceptada")

        case 2:
            loadIdeas(idRole:[0,1], id_user: 1, estado: "pendiente")

        case 3:
            loadIdeas(idRole:[0,1], id_user: 1, estado: "rechazada")

        default:
            loadIdeas(idRole:[0,1], id_user: 1, estado: "todas")
    }

}
```

And I refresh the data in "loadIdeas" function like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.table.tableView.reloadData() // Refrescamos el contenido de la tabla
            }
```

Data is changed correctly every time I select another segment but the segmented control always keeps the first segment selected before reload data.

Help me, please. I've been wasting my time with this for hours and I haven't found any similar situation in the web that can help me

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(cells[indexPath.row].cell == 1){
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomHeaderCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomHeaderCell
        cell.menuLabel.text = cells[indexPath.row].titulo

        return cell
    }
    else if(cells[indexPath.row].cell == 2){
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SegmentedControlCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! SegmentedControlCell
        cell.table = self

        return cell
    }
    else{
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! MyTableViewCell
        cell.labelTitulo.text = cells[indexPath.row].titulo
        cell.labelDescripcion.text = cells[indexPath.row].descripcion
        cell.labelEstado.text = cells[indexPath.row].estado
        cell.labelFecha.text = cells[indexPath.row].fecha
        cell.labelDepartamento.text = cells[indexPath.row].departamento
        //cell.imageView?.image = cells[indexPath.row].imagen

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) method?

Comment: I'm new in iOS swift, so maybe my code is a disaster:

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the first comment with that part of my code

Comment: great! Everyone starts at the same place.  let me know if my answer makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UITableView` data source is an unusual API to get used to. The table view itself doesn't know (or remember) anything about your data, so you have to fully specify everything in the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method. In other words, for the `SegmentedControlCell` case, you need to have some way of saving the currently selected segment and restoring it as needed.

That probably means having some property on whatever class is in your `cells` array that corresponds to the selected segment. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I understand what you say, and that make sense but I don't know how to do that because of my classes structure. It's being tricky to me to handle this kind of UI classes